# Trying to count particular column from three different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

**Master table**

```
SerNo   HospitalId  CityId
1       1           1
2       1           1
3       2           2
4       3           2
5       1           1
```

**HospitalMaster**

```
HospitalId  HospitalName
1           ABC
2           XYZ
```

**CityMaster**

```
CityId      City
1           Delhi
2           Bombay
```

Result
I need something like this

```
City    TotalHospital
Delhi   1
Bombay  2
```

I tried joining the tables but I keep getting the total rows of the columns and not of the hospitals.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.City,COUNT(DISTINCT HospitalID)TotalHospital 
FROM CityMaster C
JOIN Master_table M ON M.CityId=C.CityId
GROUP BY C.City
```

Answer (score 1):

Left join the city master table to a subquery which finds the hospital counts for each city.  Note carefully that we only count distinct hospitals, because a hospital city relationship may appear more than once in the master table.

```
SELECT t1.City, COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS TotalHospital
FROM CityMaster t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT CityId, COUNT(DISTINCT HospitalId) cnt
    FROM Master
    GROUP BY CityID
) t2
    ON t1.CityId = t2.CityId;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `join`

```
select M.City,count(distinct M.HospitalId) from CityMaster C inner join Master M ON C.CityId = M.CityId
group by M.City
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using `JOIN`
Just replace #city, #hospital, #table with your table names.

```
select C.City,T.CityId from #city C,#hosp H,#table T WHERE T.CityId = C.CityId AND T.HospitalId = H.HospitalId Group by C.City,T.CityId
```

Answer (score 0):

As we need city name along with count, we can get by join city master and master tables.

```
    select max(C.cityname), count(distinct M.HospitalId) 
      from CityMaster C 
inner join Master M 
        on C.Cityid = M.CityId
  group by M.cityid
```

Comment: You should consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Done please check